# Question concerning the proof Perron-Frobenius Theorem in 2d-case

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question concerning the following part of proof of the Perron-Frobenius Theorem in 2 dimensions (found in "Introduction to Symbolic Dynamics and Coding" by Douglas Lind and Brian Marcus).

[image: Screenshot, page 1]

It is said that the function $f\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$ is unique and continuous. My question is: Why unique and why continous?

As far as I see, one can use 
$$
\frac{Av_t}{\lVert Av_t\rVert}=v_{f(t)}=\begin{bmatrix}f(t)\\1-f(t)\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
to compute (where $\lVert w\rVert=\lvert w_1\rvert + \lvert w_2\rvert$) that

$$
f(t)=\frac{at+b(t-1)}{\lvert at+b(t-1)\rvert+ \lvert ct-d(t-1)\rvert}
$$

Maybe this already answers my question because this seems to be an unique relation and a continuous function.